# Is 'swear off' in 'He was sworn off as chiefminister of state yesterday' correct?

Tags: error

He was sworn off as chief minister of the state yesterday. (incorrect??)

He was sworn in as chief minister of the state yesterday. (correct for sure)

whats wrong in 'sworn off' sworn off means stop doing something. so he resigned yesterday..throw some light

Comment: Note that *to swear off [some activity]* usually occurs in the constructions *(He has sworn off alcohol, He is sworn off alcohol)* rather than the more "active" form *He swore off alcohol*. Your first example is incorrect, but most native speakers would easily understand the intended meaning, and it wouldn't necessarily be seen as a *serious* error. It's probably mistakenly influenced by *He was **signed off** as chief minister*.

Comment: To "swear" someone in to an office means to receive or witness the oath which they are required to swear. We don't ordinarily require an oath when someone leaves office; if we did require an oath, that would presumably be called "swearing" them "out".

Answer (score 1):

If you swear in  a person, you administer an oath to him.

If you swear off something, you promise to give it up. For example, he swore off smoking.

So the first sentence is correct, but the second is not.
.

Answer (score 1):

"swear off" means to promise to abstain from something. It isn't really a correct way to say that someone was removed from a job or position.

Some better ways to say that would be "he resigned" if he left the job by his choice, or "he was dismissed" if he left the job and it was not by his choice. If he is giving up that line of work, or giving up working altogether, you could also say "he retired".

If you don't want to say whose decision or was, or if you don't know, I don't know of any analogous phrase that means exactly the same thing. You might have to reword it as something like "he no longer works there".

Answer (score -4):

Second sentanve is passive conversation means he was sworn in by someone as a chief person.

Now in first sentence He sworn off means he will sworn off by himself so it is active conversation.

Thus , the correct statement would be.

He sworn off as chief minister of the state yesterday.